# How can I change Fn keys usage based on application?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, keyboard

I would like to know if there is any application that can enable you use use Fn keys differently based on the current application.

For example in terminal or you favourite IDE you want to use them as standard function keys but for other applications you want to keep the default Apple keys.

Comment: The new MacBook with TouchBar does exactly what you asked for (six years ago).

Comment: Unfortunately, the preference for the TouchBar function does not carry over to the external keyboard. So I still use Fluor on my TouchBar MacBook. (It's a great app too!)

Answer (score 45):

[Fluor](https://github.com/Pyroh/Fluor) is a relative newcomer to this space that does exactly what you want:

> Fluor is a tool that allows you to automatically change the behaviour of the keyboard's fn keys depending on the active application.

It is open source, works on macOs Sierra and is actively developed (as of March 2017).

Comment: Indeed, Fluor does exactly this. Really good. :)

Comment: Also very easy to install and run: `brew cask install fluor`, then just run from the Applications menu. Once Palua stopped working I migrated to Fluor and am very happy with it

Comment: FYI: @checketts is referring to Homebrew: https://brew.sh/

Comment: github says "This README is out-of-date" - but there is no references where to find up-to-date info

Comment: Good news from 2022. It's still working on M1. (macOS Monterey 12.1)

Comment: for me it doesn't work (Monterey 12.3.1) anymore :( .. it starts, but I cant see it in the status bar and can't configure anything.

Comment: Good news from 2023. It's working without a hitch on M2 Air with Ventura, installed with homebrew.

Answer (score 10):

[**FunctionFlip**](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) might be what you're looking for.

> **FunctionFlip**'s purpose is simply to disable the special features — rewind, play, mute, etc. — on the function keys. For example, if you "flip" F7, F8, and F9, those keys — only those keys — will revert back to normal F keys. Press the fn key with the special key to get the special function back. That is, the "special" and "normal" functions are flipped.
>
> To assign a custom shortcuts to your reclaimed keys, use a program like Quicksilver or Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: I've edited your post with more information, @ron, but just pasting links is not how things work here. Please the the [faq] for more.

Comment: @LoïcWolff No problem.

Comment: FunctionFlip does not seem to work any more since Big Sur.

Answer (score 10):

[Palua](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/palua/id431494195?mt=12) will do exactlly what you need.

> Introducing Palua, the easy way to quickly switch the mode of your Function Keys on any Mac keyboard!
>
> You need to run a game, or start a graphic application, or work on a
>   project that need F1-F12 as function keys, just hit option+command+TAB
>   and the switch will happen.
>
> Smart Mode: Key mode changes with the application that has the focus.

Comment: The link to Palua doesn't work, go here https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/palua/id431494195?mt=12

Comment: Unfortunately Palua doesn't work with el capitan. I ended up setting the default to function keys (with keyboard pref pane) as I generally use those and using Keyboard Maestro to remap some of them back to the special apple keys.

Comment: As of today Palua has disappeared from the App Store and internet in general.

Comment: I am not certain, but I think Palua used to work on El Capitan.  I tried running it from bash, /Applications/Palua.app/Contents/MacOS/Palua, but got this error. "2016-03-19 23:07:40.302 Palua[21714:183915] Palua must exit, the Mac Apple Store Receipt is invalid."

Comment: @ksr013 I was very disappointed not being able to find Palua any more. I started to love this small app. Any idea where it could've gone?

Answer (score 3):

There is an app - [FNable](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fnable/id469617097?mt=12) - that can help you (works with El Capitan as well).

It can switch Fn keys based on app or using a shortcut.

It is no longer available on App Store, so here is their website: https://fnable.com/

Comment: No longer available in the App Store.  Haha they all disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what keys you need, but for me the easiest solution was to use all of them as standard function keys amnd using [bowtie](http://bowtieapp.com/) with global shortcuts to keep F7-F12 as media keys, while having F1-F6 as standard function keys.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Palua for about a decade.  It left the app store about the time Apple was cracking down on some apps that they felt violated allowed scope of action.  Fortunately, I've been able to copy it from one machine to the next.  As of Feb 2023, It also works on my 2022 MBP running Monterrey 14.3.  I'm glad to hear there may be other options, but this has really been bulletproof across the years, OS, and machines.

The one glitch happened last night:  I had an error on 2013 MBA 10.14 saying it was corrupted and asking me to reinstall.  I copied from my desktop and it's working again.  I did have to put in my Apple ID and password, but it authenticated even though it's no longer downloadable from that source.