# Use only one function key as standard function key

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I'd like F2 to used as a standard function key. (ie, when I press F2 my screen won't brighten it will send an F2 to the application)

At the same time I'd like the rest of the function keys to do their respective special operations, such as lowering/increasing volume.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Without some modifications to the system or a special app for that purpose, short answer, no.  Speaking of special apps tho, this link might be where you'll find your answer.  FunctionFlip might be your thing.

[How can I change Fn keys usage based on application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28722/how-can-i-change-fn-keys-usage-based-on-application)

Comment: here's the link to FunctionFlip

http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/